# What is the alternative wsimport in Java 11?

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-11, wsimport

I have use wsimport in Ant with Java 8. There it is working, but after migrating to Java 11, I am getting errors.

I am using below configuration:

```xml
<exec executable="${java6.home}/../bin/wsimport">
  <arg line="-s ${src.java.dir} -p com.emc.srm.easyconfig.wsclient.wsapi -Xnocompile ${ws.db.wsdl}" />
</exec>
```

I getting below error in Java 11

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/patana1/workspace/Java-11-Goldfinger-SRM/APGv-java-11-Goldfinger-branch/installer/product/device-config-wizard/build.xml:95: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "${java6.home}/../bin/wsimport": error=2, No such file or directory
```

What is the alternative for this in Ant with Java 11?